# How can I preemptively load a web page or resource?

Tags: javascript, html, loading, preload, prefetch

I'm working on a web app which is pretty resource intensive. The user works on the first page and submits some data before going on to the second stage.

The problem is that the web page for the second stage takes too long to load, which breaks the flow of the whole process, especially since the web app is targeted at countries which don't have the fastest internet connections.

Is there any way for me to preemptively load the web page for the second stage (or the resources used by that web page) in the background the moment the user visits the first web page?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the help of the [`prefetch` attribute for `<link>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/) .

When these are used, the browser downloads designated documents (pages, images, etc.)  the user will likely visit after the current page preemptively into the cache.

### The `prefetch` attribute

This directive tells the browser to fetch a resource that will probably be needed for the next navigation. That means that the resource will likely be fetched with extremely low priority since everything that's required in the current page takes precedence over a resource on the next page. That makes prefetch far more suited to speeding up the next page rather than the current one.

Syntax: 
`<link rel="prefetch" href="(url)">`

Examples:

```
<!-- full page -->
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/example-page/" />

<!-- just an image -->
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/example-image.png" />
```

Additionally, if you're loading content dynamically, you can use this to preemptively load resources:

### The `preload` attribute

Unlike the `prefetch` attribute, the new `preload` rel value targets the *current navigation*. It also supports the extra `as` attribute, that tells the browser what it will be downloading. Possible `as` values include:

- `script`
- `style`
- `image`
- `media`
- `document`

We can use preload to load images ahead of time, along with the media attribute in order to restrict the downloading of an image to devices of a certain resolution:

`<link rel="preload" as="image" href="map.png" media="(max-width: 600px)">`

There are tons of other attributes to the `<link>` tag which may also come in useful: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp.

Sources:

- https://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch
- https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480001/So-You-Want-To-Pre-Load-Huh.htm

You can check the browser-compatibility of these features here:
`prefetch`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch
`preload`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload